# Can anyone help me colorcode my time blocks using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to color code my time block columns on my planner for some time now and cant seem to figure it out. I would like it to be colorcoded so that past hours show as red, current hour shows as green and future hours show as blue. When I inspect it it says "date is not defined." Currently on the webpage, all of the hours just show as white.

Here is my HTML (there are 8 rows in total, 9am-5pm)

```
 <div class = "container" spellcheck="false">
    <div class = "row my-row">
        <div class = "col my-col col-a1 colorcode" id = "9"> 9am </div>
        <div class = "col my-col col-a2 edit_cont" > </div>
        <div class = "col my-col col-a3 edit_btn"> edit </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "row my-row" >
        <div class = "col my-col col-b1 colorcode" id = "10"> 10am </div>
        <div class = "col my-col col-b2 edit_cont">  </div>
        <div class = "col my-col col-b3 edit_btn"> edit </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.7.0/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And here is my Javascript/Jquery:

```
});

    const colorcode = document.getElementsByClassName("colorcode");


    var currentHour = date.getHours();
    $('.colorcode').each(function(){
        var val = parseInt($(this).prop('id'));
        if(val > currentHour && val < currentHour+6){
            $(this).css('background-color','Blue');
        }else if(val < currentHour && val > currentHour-6){
            $(this).css('background-color','Red');
        }else if(val === currentHour){
            $(this).css('background-color','Green');
        }else{
            $(this).css('background-color','White');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue you have with your code is that `date` is not defined.

You can replace that piece of code with `var currentHour = (new Date()).getHours();`. See a snippet below

```js
var currentHour = (new Date()).getHours();
$('.colorcode')
  .each(function(){
    var val = parseInt($(this).prop('id'));
    if(val > currentHour && val < currentHour + 6){
      $(this).css('background-color','Blue');
    }else if(val < currentHour && val > currentHour-6){
      $(this).css('background-color','Red');
    }else if(val === currentHour){
      $(this).css('background-color','Green');
    }else{
      $(this).css('background-color','White');
    }
  });
```

```css
.container {
  display:table;
}

.container .row {
  display:table-row;
}

.container .row .col {
  display:table-cell;
  padding:5px;
  border:1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" spellcheck="false">
    <div class="row my-row">
        <div class="col my-col col-a1 colorcode" id="8"> 8am </div>
        <div class="col my-col col-a2 edit_cont" > </div>
        <div class="col my-col col-a3 edit_btn"> edit </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row my-row">
        <div class="col my-col col-a1 colorcode" id="9"> 9am </div>
        <div class="col my-col col-a2 edit_cont" > </div>
        <div class="col my-col col-a3 edit_btn"> edit </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row my-row" >
        <div class="col my-col col-b1 colorcode" id="10"> 10am </div>
        <div class="col my-col col-b2 edit_cont">  </div>
        <div class="col my-col col-b3 edit_btn"> edit </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row my-row" >
        <div class="col my-col col-b1 colorcode" id="11"> 11am </div>
        <div class="col my-col col-b2 edit_cont">  </div>
        <div class="col my-col col-b3 edit_btn"> edit </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row my-row" >
        <div class="col my-col col-b1 colorcode" id="12"> 12pm </div>
        <div class="col my-col col-b2 edit_cont">  </div>
        <div class="col my-col col-b3 edit_btn"> edit </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row my-row" >
        <div class="col my-col col-b1 colorcode" id="13"> 1pm </div>
        <div class="col my-col col-b2 edit_cont">  </div>
        <div class="col my-col col-b3 edit_btn"> edit </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row my-row">
        <div class="col my-col col-a1 colorcode" id="14"> 2pm </div>
        <div class="col my-col col-a2 edit_cont" > </div>
        <div class="col my-col col-a3 edit_btn"> edit </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: NOTE: I've only included few hours of the day, so to actually implement this, you would simply expand this set to the full hours of the day in 24hour format

Comment: @Daedalus how so? It covers all points and provides a working answer the question

Comment: I misread the code/example at first.  My bad.  Going to delete my misinformed comment.